# How to change index values after sorting a vector? c++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of `pair<int, struct>` where `int` corresponds to the index.
I sort this vector by `struct`, and want my output vector's int values to correspond to the new sorting.

How could I do this?

```
<1,zone> <2, car> <3, apple>
```

sorts to :

```
<3, apple>, <2, car>, <1, zone>
```

Now I want to change those ints to correspond to their new indices in the vector. Ie the pair with apple would be 1. How do I do this?

Hoping for an STL way so that I don't just iterate over the vector and change them manually.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  You don't need to store the index in the element in order to get it.  If you do `&reference_to_object_in_vector - &vector_name[0]` you'll get it's index.

Comment: If you have to, you can always just iterate over the vector with a counter setting `.first = counter;` as you go... (but you really don't need the `std::pair` if you are just concerned with the `std::string`) Closest without iterating is `std::transform` -- which just does the iteration for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just add in the reindexing in your sort function.

```
void bubbleSort(vector);   //generic bubble sort
{  
    int i, j;  
    for (i = 0; i < vector.size()-1; i++){      
        for (j = 0; j < vector.size()-i-1; j++){
            if (vector[j].second > vector[j+1].second){  
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
                vector[j].first = j+1;   //
                vector[j+1].first = j;   // updating index values here 
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Or you can have a simple for loop that goes though the vector and reindexes it.

```
vector<pair<int, struct>> myvector;

for(int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++){
    myvector[i].first = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck on the problem, you can sort with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and reorder the index part of your pair beginning at `1` using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) but it will require `-std=c++14` to make use of the *lambda capture initializer*. Otherwise you will have to use a loop to reorder the pair index.

The basic approach would be:

```
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> vp {{1, "zone"}, 
                                                 {2, "car"},
                                                 {3, "apple"}};
    ...
    /* sort by string */
    std::sort (vp.begin(), vp.end(), [](const std::pair<int, std::string>& a, 
                                        const std::pair<int, std::string>& b) {
                                            return a.second < b.second; });
    /* reorder integers */
    std::transform (vp.begin(), vp.end(), vp.begin(), 
                    [n = 1](std::pair<int, std::string>& a) mutable { 
                        a.first = n++;
                        return a = {a.first, a.second}; });
```

Adding a short bit of output to show the results along with the required headers, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main (void) {

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> vp {{1, "zone"}, 
                                                 {2, "car"},
                                                 {3, "apple"}};
    std::cout << "pre-sort/transform:\n";
    for (auto& i : vp)
        std::cout << i.first << ", " << i.second << '\n';

    /* sort by string */
    std::sort (vp.begin(), vp.end(), [](const std::pair<int, std::string>& a, 
                                        const std::pair<int, std::string>& b) {
                                            return a.second < b.second; });
    /* reorder integers */
    std::transform (vp.begin(), vp.end(), vp.begin(), 
                    [n = 1](std::pair<int, std::string>& a) mutable { 
                        a.first = n++;
                        return a = {a.first, a.second}; });

    std::cout << "\npost-sort/transform:\n";
    for (auto& i : vp)
        std::cout << i.first << ", " << i.second << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vectorpair
pre-sort/transform:
1, zone
2, car
3, apple

post-sort/transform:
1, apple
2, car
3, zone
```

While there is nothing wrong with using the `std::vector<std::pair>`, if you are not making any other use of the index, consider using a simple `std::vector<std::string>` and doing away with the `std::pair`. You can always generate the index when needed.